# Strech To Fit Volley NetworkImageView

Tags: android, image, android-volley, networkimageview

I'm using NetworkImageView to display images , the problem is the width and the height of the image is not fitting with the NetworkImageView , and the image will take it's original size and a white space will appear in the NetworkImageView . I don't wan't to change the image size as well ..

```
    <com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:id="@+id/thumb2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="170dp" />
```

Comment: post your layout file to show how you define NetworkImageView.

Comment: ok  I added it check now

Answer (score 0):

If you want the image size to stay same then set layout_width & height to wrap_content.

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

otherwise just add `android:scaleType` with appropriate value that suits you.

```
android:scaleType="fitCenter"
```

or

```
android:scaleType="centerCrop"
```

You can see full list of available values here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html

Comment: it's better than befor , but same thing a white space to the right of the image is shown